# Different result of after converting 3DES program from C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, translate, 3des

I have a c# program as follow:

```
public static string Encrypt(string sClear, string sKey)
        {
            sClear = "4140700104596085";
            sKey = "222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222";

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            byte[] bData = new byte[16];
            byte[] bKey = new byte[24];

            // Convert from hex to decimal
            FromHexToDecimal(sClear).CopyTo(bData, 0);
            FromHexToDecimal(sKey).CopyTo(bKey, 0);

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = DESCryptoExtensions.CreateWeakEncryptor(cryptoProvider, bKey, cryptoProvider.IV);
            byte[] result = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(bData, 0, bData.Length);

            return BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 16);
        }
```

My clear text is "4140700104596085", and my key is "222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222", and this program will return me "0C90320B7B9EC798" as result.

Now I am trying to do it in java code, and here is my code:

```
public static String encryptToString(String message) throws Exception {
      message = "4140700104596085";
      final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
      final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
              .getBytes("utf-8"));
      final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
      for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
          keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
      }

      final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
      final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
      // cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

      final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
      final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);

      return Hex.encodeHexString(cipherText).substring(0, 16);
  }
```

As u can see, I comment the `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);`, because I will hit `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: ECB mode cannot use IV` error.

Even I comment it, the result I get is still different, it is `f8f8739fb41259d6`. I believe something wrong in my code in Java, any ideas?

I tried google on it, but its not that straight forward to translate.

Comment: Note that you're MD5 hashing the key in the java version, and then doing another little routine on it. In C# you're not doing that at all.

Comment: Even I replace it to `final byte[] digestOfPassword = "222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222".getBytes("utf-8");`, it still not getting the same result. I suspect something wrong in my java code, which is not same with what c# doing.

Comment: Note that if you replace `digestOfPassword`, you're still running the for loop modifying `keyBytes`, which you're not doing in C#.

Comment: I am so stupid. After see your comment, I manage to get it. Should I close this question? or just leave it?

Comment: You could fix your code and add it as an answer :) Although maybe not doing the exact same thing, someone might find some value in having the equivalent C# and Java code in future.

Comment: Ok. But actually its my careless. I didnt read the c# code correctly and straight post here.

Comment: It's up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I should follow the code in C#.

Thus, I remove

```
final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
      final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
              .getBytes("utf-8"));
      final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
      for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
          keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
      }
```

And replace with

```
final byte[] keyBytes = fromHexToDecimal("222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
```

And the `fromHexToDecimal` method will be as follow:

```
public static byte[] fromHexToDecimal(String hex) {

      int len = hex.length() / 2;
      byte[] result = new byte[len];

      for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j = j + 2) {
        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
        c = c.append(hex.charAt(j)).append(hex.charAt(j+1));
        short s = (short) Integer.parseInt(c.toString(), 16);
        result[i] = (byte)(s & 0xff);
      }


      return result;
    }
```